# Why does this usage of recur in Clojure cause a crash?

Tags: recursion, clojure, tree

I have this data structure:

```
(def initial-map {:name "Root"
                  :children [{:name "Child1" :children [{:name "Grandchild1"}]}
                             {:name "Child2"}
                             {:name "Child3"}]})
```

And I need to turn it into something like this:

`[["Root" 0] ["Child1" 1] ["Child2" 1] ["Child3" 1] ["Grandchild1" 2]]`

Where the numbers represent the depth of the node in the data structure.

I've written this function to try and go from the first to the second:

```
(defn node-xform [ret nodes depth]
  (if empty? nodes)
  ret
  (recur (conj ret (map #(vector (:name %) depth) nodes))
         (flatten (map #(:children %) nodes))
         (inc depth)))
```

And am calling it like this

```
(node-xform [] (vector initial-map) 0)
```

But when I do, it either times out or crashes my computer... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` form should look like this:

```
(if conditional-expr true-expr false-expr)
```

The `false-expr` is actually optional, with a default value of `nil` if it's left off—but I don't think that's what you want. It looks like you want to return `ret` when `nodes` is empty, and `recur` otherwise:

```
(defn node-xform [ret nodes depth]
  (if (empty? nodes) ; <-- fixed this line
    ret
    (recur (conj ret (map #(vector (:name %) depth) nodes))
           (flatten (map #(:children %) nodes))
           (inc depth)))) ; <-- added another close-paren here for the "if"
```

I didn't actually test to see if that returns your expected answer, but that will at least get rid of your infinite recursion problem.

Your code results in an infinite loop because `node-xform` *always* executes the `recur` form, which results in infinite tail recursion. Correcting the syntax for the `if` form makes it so that the `recur` expression is only executed when `nodes` is non-empty.